# Paginating and retriving data with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Hi 
I'm trying to  to do pagination from the KindsController but with data from the LinkModel

Tables :

```
  Kinds       links          
     id           id
     name         title
     order        url
                  kind_id
                  order
```

model:

```
class Kind extends AppModel{

        var $name = 'Kind';
        var $hasMany = 'Link';
    }
```

controller:

```
class KindsController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'Kinds';
    var $paginate = array(

        'Kind'=> array(
            'limit' => 12,
            'order'=> array('Kind.order'=>'ASC')

        )

    );

}
```

desired result (view) ;

```
 Kind.name ( numbers of links )
    links.name
    ........
    ..........

    Kind.name ( numbers of links )
    links.name
    ........
    ..........
```

i'm using the kinds.order and links.order to control how the data is displayed in the view
from an admin area.

i need to retrive data from the kinds table ordered by kinds.order ASC and the number of links, and the links data  ordered by links.order

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define order in the relation like this:

```
class Kind extends AppModel{
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Link' => array(
            'className' => 'Link',
            'order' => 'Link.name'
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: add 'contain' => array('Link') to the paginate property and call $kinds = $this->paginate();

Comment: thank you nik the order now is ok. how can i get the number of links for every kind from the links table ? i khnow that the query will be like this : SELECT count(*) FROM links WHERE kind_id = id

Comment: Getting the count could be done with counterCache. Check this one: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count Alternatively if the links are show in the table you can always get the number with count($data['Kind'][$i]['Link']). Just check the output in the view

Comment: Hi i need the number of links for a specific kind, i think with the counterCache i can only get the total number of links.  count($data['Kind'][$i]['Link']) is a good solution. thank you